# sql Row_Number function is not working after created in table

Tags: sql, view, where-clause, row-number

I hope this isn't a repeated discussion.  I did search through the forums and didn't find anything that related to my problem.  I love this site by the way. It has helped me for a couple years now and I usually will get all my questions solved by searching this site.

Anyway, I am running into an issue in SQL with the ROW_NUMBER() function.  I created a view that involves joining a different view and a table and in the view I pulled fields from both the view and the table, but I also created two fields that was a  ROW_Number() field called seq_number and another field called seq_alpha.

Seq Number field is:

ROW_NUMBER() over(order by book_date, room, start) as seq_number,

The seq_alpha field is a case field that is based on what the row number is to give an alpha letter instead.

For example

case ROW_NUMBER() over(order by book_date, Room, Start)
when 1 then 'A'
when 2 then 'B'
when 3 then 'C'
....
End as seq_alpha

When I created the view for testing purposes I used a WHERE clause and everything worked exactly the way it should.  I then commented out the Where clause and had the table created.

Then after the view was created I tried to pull the created view and used the same Where clause that worked when creating the view but now did it like:

select *
from created_view
where (same as I used for testing)

But now what happens is the seq_number field looks at the entire view instead of letting the where clause filter out the results.  All the other data pulls correctly, but the seq_number and seq_alpha fields don't.  So instead of having the seq number be 1-22 in my 22 results it is 400,000 range and the seq_alpha field doesn't even display anything because I only went up to 51 in my case.

Has anyone had similar issues with trying to pull a row_number field after it is created and the field not filtering the results with the where clause?

Thanks for your help in advance!

**EDIT**
After Mikael's response it seems unlikely that I am able to create a row_number field in a view and then query the view afterward and have it work the way I want.  So, my next question is is there a way to create an alpha sequence based on the row number that I can put in a view and be able to query later and be able to have it work correct based on the where clause?  Or do I just need to create the alpha sequence field every time I would pull this view?

J

Comment: What database engine are we talking about?

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server 2008? Sorry I want to make sure I give you the right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`row_number()` enumerates the rows it sees when it is executed after the where clause is applied.

This will enumerate the whole table

```
select ID, 
       row_number() over(order by ID) as rn
from YourTable
```

and this will enumerate all rows where ID < 10

```
select ID,
       row_number() over(order by ID) as rn
from YourTable
where ID < 10
```

If you create a view that queries the whole table

```
create view ViewYourTable as
select ID,
       row_number() over(order by ID) as rn
from YourTable
```

and then query the view with a where clause ID < 10

```
select T.*
from ViewYourTable as T
where T.ID < 10
```

you are doing the same as if you used a derived table.

```
select T.*
from (
     select ID,
            row_number() over(order by ID) as rn
     from YourTable
     ) as T
where T.ID < 10
```

The where clause is applied after the rows are enumerated.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mikael!  So, just to make sure I am understanding this correctly..  When I created the view first and did the testing with the Where clause the Row Number function started enumerating AFTER the where clause was applied.  Now when I query the view the row number is enumerating BEFORE the where clause is applied right?

Comment: @jammille Yes,  when you have the where clause *in* the view you are enumerating *after* the where clause is applied. If you enumerate in the view and apply a where clause on the query against the view you are enumerating rows *before* the where clause is applied.

Comment: the seq_number field was just more for verification.  What I would need is to be able to create an alpha field that would assign a letter based on the row number.  Do you know of a way I could put this into a view, but then be able to query it after and also be able to work with the where clause?

Comment: @jammille i don't see a way to push the where clause down below row_number in the view.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this!  I am thinking I am going to just build the where clause in the view then.  Thanks again!

Comment: @jammille if you have a fixed shape of the where clause where only the values you compare against is different you could use a table valued function to do what you want.

Comment: At least if you are using SQL Server